# two itunes libraries - one on external hard disk

Tags: iphone, itunes, macos

I have a macbook pro as my everyday machine, but since my music collection was getting big and my hard disk is small, I decided to utilize an external hard disk that I had and was not used for anything. On the external HDD I created a new iTunes Library and copied all my music there. Some small amount of it I left on my MBP so I could listen on the go. When I was home and I wanted to refresh the MBP's music, I'd connect the external HDD and if I downloaded any new music in my iTunes Library I'd copied them to the external HDD too.
This way the external HDD contains the most current contents of my music collection.
It was ok, until I recently decided to buy an iPhone.

I synced the iPhone to my MBP's iTunes Library and now trying to copy some new music from the external HDD iTunes Library I'm being told that in order to do that I have to delete everything that's on my iPhone.

Is there any different option?

Answer (score 2):

iPhone can be synced to only one iTunes library at any given moment. If you want to add songs to the iPhone, you must add them to your MBP's iTunes library and then sync to the iPhone.

Comment: I thought about that but I was hoping there'd be something less labour intensive :) How would I proceed if I want the current apps and iphone settings I have to be transferred to the other library and to start syncing only with it?

Comment: First of all to ensure that in the worst case scenario you can get your iPhone back to its current state, do a full sync on the MBP library, that will create a back up. Then change library and connect your iPhone, to get all your Apps onto your external library right click on the iPhone in the tool bar and select "Transfer purchases".

Comment: Actually I'm not quite sure about the apps :) The last time I did that (synced between my old laptop and my older one) I lost just the music and video stuff. The apps stayed intact. Then I just redownloaded the apps from iTunes and it was all fine. But that's just me - I think LC1983's advice is better in terms of recovery :)

Comment: while it is strictly right that iOS can be synced to only one iTunes, there are ways to sync iPhone with more than 1 computer as long as all of them have the exact same library (to trick iOS).

Comment: refraining what I said previously, I don't know for how long there are oficial ways to sync iOS to multiple iTunes: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9350/itunes-library-sync-between-two-computers/9352#9352

Comment: From notes section: iPod shuffle and iPhone are intended for use with a single computer. You cannot load music from multiple computers or iTunes libraries onto iPod shuffle and iPhone like you can with other devices.